# Selecting element of a list by its subsets

Tags: python, list, functional-programming

I have the following lists:

```
t0=[['a'],
 ['a', 'h'],
 ['a', 'd', 'k', 'r', 'v'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'k'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 's', 'u'],
 ['a', 'b', 'f', 't'],
 ['a', 'b', 'e', 'l', 'n', 'o'],
 ['a', 'b', 'd', 'n', 'o'],
 ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'n', 'o'],
 ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'm', 'n', 'o', 't']]
```

and

```
t1=[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'd']]
```

For each element in t1 I want to go through t0 and select the element where t1 is the subset, the out put should then look like this:

```
[[["a", "b", "c", "k"], ["a", "b", "c", "s", "u"], ["a", "b", "f", "t"], ["a", "b", "e", "l", "n", "o"], ["a", "b", "d", "n", "o"], ["a", "b", "d", "e", "n", "o"], ["a", "b", "d", "e", "m", "n", "o", "t"]],
 [["a", "b", "c", "k"], ["a", "b", "c", "s", "u"]], 
 [["a", "d", "k", "r", "v"], ["a", "b", "d", "n", "o"], ["a","b", "d", "e", "n", "o"], ["a", "b", "d", "e", "m", "n", "o","t"]]]
```

So for instance the first element is `['a','b']` thus the first element of output would be those elements of t0 where `['a','b']` is the subset of them.
I wonder how one write a function to do this?

Comment: how is this pandas? is it a series?

Comment: You might want to show your efforts and ask question that is related to your approach. People here can help you solve a problem, not give you a solution altogether.

Comment: I've added the tag in case someone has a solution using Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
[[j for j in t0 if set(i) <= set(j)] for i in t1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 2 you could do:

```
map(lambda x: filter(lambda y: set(x) <= set(y), t0), t1 )
```

In python 3 that would be:

```
list(map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: set(x) <= set(y), t0)), t1 ))
```